# Update the content of Android Sherlock tabs

Tags: android, mobile, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I am using Sherlock tabs to implement tabs. It's all working fine but I want to do one more thing, and here's the scenario for that:

Suppose on a specific tab, a fragment is loaded. Within that fragment, when a button is clicked, I will have to load another fragment yet I want the tabs to stay.

How do I achieve this feature? What method can help here?

Comment: if that what u use http://actionbarsherlock.com there is an documentation u must read it.

Comment: You want to load fragment into current tab or into another, or to add new tab with that new fragment?

Comment: @Armen Tabs are tabs.  Fragments are fragments.  If you want a FragmentTransaction, it does not conflict with the selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
I used Handler and Messenger to send data between tabs and update UI which solved my problem.